Deepgram Text To Speech while streaming to twilio call sounds cropped
Im streaming TSS from deepgram to twlio call but the audio sound cropped.
Example:
Hello. What. is. your. Name. ?.
instead of Hello what is your name?
My similar code with Elevenlabs works perfectly.
Deepgram Code:
from src.tools.text_chunker import text_chunker
import os 
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import base64
import json
import requests
load_dotenv()
#deepgram api key
DEEPGRAM_API_KEY = os.environ['DEEPGRAM_API_KEY']


async def text_to_speech_input_streaming_deepgram(call_sid, voice_id, model, text_iterator, twilio_ws, stream_sid, listen_task):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Token {DEEPGRAM_API_KEY}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    DEEPGRAM_URL = 'https://api.deepgram.com/v1/speak?model=aura-asteria-en&encoding=mulaw&sample_rate=8000'

    async for text in text_chunker(text_iterator):
        payload = {"text": text}
        with requests.post(DEEPGRAM_URL, stream=True, headers=headers, json=payload) as r:
            for chunk in r:  # Adjusted chunk size here
                if chunk:
                    await stream(chunk, twilio_ws, stream_sid)


async def stream(audio_stream, twilio_ws, stream_sid):
    b64_audio_chunk = base64.b64encode(audio_stream).decode('utf-8')
    message = json.dumps({'event': 'media', 'streamSid': stream_sid,
                          'media': {'payload': b64_audio_chunk}})
    await twilio_ws.send_text(message)


I already tried buffering the audio and sending it to twilio every 15 words and it helps a little bit but every 15 words I hear a TAP where the audio is beign cut.
